# Trying to read json files from S3 bucket but unable to do it

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Here is the code that I tried to test. But it says AWS credentials issue. Not sure how is it this issue when I have provided the access keys value.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
aws_access_key_id = "******"
aws_secret_access_key= "*****"
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", aws_access_key_id)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", aws_secret_access_key)
object_list = [k for k in bucket.objects.all()]
key_list = [k.key for k in bucket.objects.all()]

paths = ['s3a://'+o.bucket_name+'/'+ o.key for o in object_list ]
dataframes = [sqlContext.read.json(path) for path in paths]

df = dataframes[0]
for idx, frame in enumerate(dataframes):
  df = df.unionAll(frame)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1225.json.
: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong [authentication properties.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/#Authentication_properties)

It should be `fs.s3a.access.key` for your access key and
`fs.s3a.secret.key` for your secret key.

Comment: I tried that too. Its still giving me error